# Unresolved reference in Pycharm for importing modules in parent directory

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, python-idle

There was a similar question but not quite what I ran into so here we go:

My directory structure:
├── PycharmProjects
  ____  ├── MyProject
_______   ├── main.py
_______ ├── ...
   ___ ├── Tools
_______ ├── web.py

To import web.py functions I use

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
from Tools.web import *
```

It works in Pycharm as well as in Idle, however the code analysis in Pycharm shows Tools and its function as 'unresolved references'. How do I solve this issue ?

I already tried:
1. **init**.py in each folder of all levels.
2. add tools folder to Project Structure, mark it Source folder (blue color)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the following, which I do, translated into your terms: put a file called, say, my_pycharm.pth into /Lib/site-packages with the following line.

```
 <drive>:/path/to/PycharmProjects
```

This essentially appends the *contents* of /PycharmProjects to the contents of /site-packages.  In other words, when import searches /site-packages for modules, it also searches /PycharmProjects.  (I do this for each installed Python version.)

Then make each project in /PycharmProjects a proper package by adding `__init__.py`.

Now, for instance, main.py can have

```
 from Tools import web
```

and it should just work.

If you share your code with someone else, they just need to put it in *their* site-packages.

Comment: I confirm this method works. This means there is no need to add custom path to Project Source to Pycharm project. The downside is if I have a ton of projects in PycharmProjects folder there could be confusing when using import statement.

Comment: Yes, all projects must have names distinct not only from each other but all dependencies downloaded into site-packages.

Answer (score 1):

There's an easier answer outlined here, for anyone who comes to this in the future:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000646984--Solved-Warnings-import-local-package-Unresolved-references-inspection

It's at the bottom:

> 1. Go to the settings "Ctrl+Alt+S" and select the next options:
> 2. Select the folder which want to convert into python sources in my case "./src" and tap in Source tag (Mark as..) then it added on the
>    left panel also tap Apply or Ok.